# Using Miles for hotels

Tags: frequent-flier-miles

I am using my united miles for hotels.

Is it worth to use $45k united miles on $149 hotel per night. 
45k is for 2 nights.

Thanks.

Comment: No one can really answer that for you.  It depends on your own personal assessment of the benefit of those nights versus alternative things you could use the miles for (which you don't mention).

Comment: The simplest comparison is to see what kind of round trip flight you could get for the same amount of miles and see if that seems worth $300 to you.

Comment: On the other hand, if you're in a system where points expire and you aren't going to fly a route where you can use those points any time soon.... And remember to consider restrictions on use when comparing. Basically, this comes back to a combination of value and _time_-value.

Comment: Make sure to compare with the real hotel price (the best price) not the rack rate.

Comment: Those points would be worth much more redeemed for a flight on United. They should be worth enough for a round trip flight in the US or a one way flight to almost anywhere in the world.

Answer (score 3):

If these point are from spending $45000, you first want to get a grip on the point value. In general, a point should be worth 1-2 cents each, i.e. $450 minimum, $900 max.

To trade for less than $450 value seems wrong.